# Does Entity Designer support many-to-many relationships with duplicate association data?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Package A has one Desktop Y and one Monitor Z. Package B has one Desktop Y and *two* Monitor Z's. I want to represent that relationship in a database created by Entity Designer.

There's a many-to-many relationship between `StandardPackage` and `StandardMachine` (which has desktops, monitors, laptops, etc). Every quarter, we update our packages, and clients place orders. They select a package, and when the order is placed, that package's `StandardMachines` dump their data (type, make, model, etc.) into newly created `Machines`.

The problem lies in the way Entity Designer creates the junction table for the `StandardPackageStandardMachine` relationship. The junction table has two columns corresponding to the IDs of the records on each end of the relationship, and the primary key for the junction table is the combination of those two IDs. So, for the example in the first paragraph, if Package A's Id is 1, Package B's Id is 2, Desktop Y's Id is 1, and Monitor Z's Id is 2, what I need is

```
StandardPackageId | StandardMachineId
------------------|------------------
         1        |         1        
         1        |         2
         2        |         1
         2        |         2
         2        |         2
```

but obviously you can't have two 2/2 records.

Is there a nice way to tell Entity Designer what I intend to do, so that it will create an auto-incrementing primary key column for the junction table? Or do I have to resort to manually creating the junction table and handling the association myself?

By the way, if someone even knows how to rephrase my question title, please do so.

Comment: The core problem is that your `Monitor Z` isn't an entity but a class.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Nope, Monitor Z is an instance of `StandardMachine`

Comment: If it was, it couldn't be in 2 packages at the same time. From your usage it's a sub-class of StandardMachine.

Comment: Sure it can. Monitor Z is a particular `StandardMachine` in the database. I call it Monitor Z purely for reference. Via a many-to-many relationship any amount of packages can contain Monitor Z. More accurately, any amount of `StandardPackages` can reference (via junction table) this particular `StandardMachine` that I call Monitor Z.

Comment: If it was an instance (of Monitor) you would be selling 1 item twice.

Comment: That's almost correct. The significance of `Standard` is that these are just shells of data that get copied to the objects that actually get created when an order is placed. The actual `Machine` table will have two separate entries, because when you order two of the same monitor, they have separate serial numbers and such. But as far as designing our offered packages, yes, it should appear that we are offering the same thing multiple times, in the same way that we ask Dell to ship us the same thing multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or do I have to resort to manually creating the junction table and handling the association myself

Yes, you have. Because the table is not a junction table, but an entity.

The semantics of a many-to-many association are subtly different from what you want to express. One record in a regular n:m association table expresses "A is related to B". In *your* table it would express "A has an instance of B".

The former expression is always redundant when repeated: "A is related to B" - OK, we knew that. The latter isn't: "A has another instance of B". So there are two *distinct* instances, which means that each instance has an *identity*. Identity is a core concept of entities.

So `StandardPackageStandardMachine` is just a regular class which represents a machine instance in a package, even though it's still a 'virtual machine'.

Answer (score 1):

What you would normally do is create a master/detail relationship.

I'm not sure of the context of what you're doing.  Typically your package would have a 1:many association of Package:Items, each item line would have it's own line number (sometimes called a sequence number), and it would have a foreign key relationship with product table.  ie, something like this:

```
ID Name
1  Package A
2  Package B

ID PkgID Line(Seq) PrdID
1  1     1         1 
2  1     2         1
3  1     3         2
4  2     1         1
5  2     2         2

ID Name
1  Monitor Y
2  Desktop Z
```

In this way, you can have as many of a single type as you want.  The reason for the ID vs Line is that Line number duplicates for each order, while ID is a unique key for the table.  Alternatively, you can make a composite key of PkgID and Line.