# Many-to-many relationship with duplicate entries

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many

I'm trying to build a many to many relationship using the entity framework and fluent API, but I'm stuck trying to allow duplicate entries.  Here is what I have:

```
public class Pizza
{
    public int PizzaId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Topping> Toppings { get; set; }
}

public class Topping
{
    public int ToppingId { get; set; }
}
```

- Any pizza should be able to have multiple toppings.
- Any topping can be applied to multiple pizzas.

So in `OnModelCreating()` I call:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Pizza>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Toppings)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("ToppingsForPizza"));
```

That give me a nice many-to-many relationship, but **the problem is I want a pizza to be able to have multiple instances of the same topping** e.g. double pepperoni

The `ToppingsForPizza` database that is generated cannot support that... i'm guessing because there needs to be a unique primary key.

Is there a way to do this?

**EDIT:** My actual problem has nothing to do with pizza, this is just the example I came up with.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Entity Designer support many-to-many relationships with duplicate association data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16551199/does-entity-designer-support-many-to-many-relationships-with-duplicate-associati)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a different primary key to your many to many relationship. That means it becomes an entity in it's own right

```
public class PizzaTopping
{   
    public int PizzaToppingId { get; set; }
    public int PizzaId { get; set; }
    public int ToppingId { get; set; }

    public virtual Pizza Pizza { get; set; }
    public virtual Topping Topping { get; set; }
}

public class Pizza
{ 
     public int PizzaId { get; set; } 
     public virtual ICollection<PizzaTopping> PizzaToppings { get; set; }
}

public class Topping
{   
     public int ToppingId { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<PizzaTopping> PizzaToppings { get; set; }
}
```

Doesn't make much sense applied to Pizzas and Toppings..... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider double pepperoni as a separate Topping. But, you can also create a third class, like below:

```
public class PizzaTopping
{
    public int PizzaId { get; set; }
    public int ToppingId { get; set; }
    public int ToppingCount { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Pizza> Pizzas { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Topping> Toppings { get; set; }
}

public class Pizza
{
    public int PizzaId { get; set; }
}

public class Topping
{
    public int ToppingId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That was just meant as an example, the real problem has nothing to do with pizza :) adding a property for count is not an option.

Comment: Well, then you don't have any other options. When you create a many-to-many relationship, EF automatically creates a third table with the primary keys from the other two tables to maintain the many-to-many relationship. And, obviously, you can't add two same records to that table.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to turn off code first and model verification, create a new primary key as described by others, create foreign keys in your relationship table for PizzaId and ToppingId, then modify your mapping to include the foreign keys.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Pizza>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Toppings)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("ToppingsForPizza")
               .MapLeftKey("PizzaId")
               .MapRightKey("ToppingId"));
```

(Because it's likely that it's a unique composite key that's preventing the addition of multiple toppings.)