# Entity Framework Many To Many Entity?

Tags: entity-framework

This is not another question concerning how to create a Many To Many relationship, but rather, how to actually take control of the entity that maps the relationship?

For example...  Many to many relationship between table Product and table Supplier.

I need a SupplierProduct that has columns specific to a product+supplier combination.

```
class SupplierProduct {
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    // additional properties specific to a S+P combo: 
    public bool IsProductAssembled { get; set; }
}
```

Some suppliers assemble, others don't.  If I have such a class, how can I use it in place of the default EF many-to-many table that it creates?

Comment: I'm not sure that can be done with EF. Then, how would you access the `IsProductAssembled` property since the mapping table  is only used to join your entities together. However, with the `SupplierProduct` class you're having, can't you just configure two one-to-many relationships? A `Product` can have multiple `SupplierProduct` , and a `Supplier` can have many `SupplierProduct`.

Comment: That's a different way of thinking about it.  It sounds good.  I'll try it out.  Just to be clear: you are saying drop the mapping table altogether (as in remove the collections from the code first classes so EF doesn't auto create a mapping table.)?

Comment: Yes, I made an answer clarifying that part.

Comment: This happens a lot. You have a many to many relationship, then you realise there is an attribute on that relationship and you have to promote it to an entity in its own right. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171514/many-to-many-relationship-with-duplicate-entries/19172837#19172837

Answer (score 2):

Use your `SupplierProduct` class as relation instead:

```
class SupplierProduct {
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    // additional properties specific to a S+P combo: 
    public bool IsProductAssembled { get; set; }
}

class Product {
    // ... lot of properties

    // Link all the suppliers of this products
    public IList<SupplierProduct> Suppliers { get; set; }
}    

class Supplier {
    // ... lot of properties

    // Link all the product this supplier supplies
    public IList<SupplierProduct> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Then, configure `Product` to have a lot of `Suppliers` and `Supplier` to have a lot of `Products`. No direct relation between `Product` and `Supplier` anymore.

Configure the model binder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
    .HasMany<SupplierProduct>(p => p.Suppliers)
    .WithRequired();

modelBuilder.Entity<Supplier>()
    .HasMany<SupplierProduct>(s => s.Products)
    .WithRequired();
```

Comment: would you please extend your answer? especially this part: `Then, configure Product to have a lot of Suppliers and Supplier to have a lot of Products. No direct relation between Product and Supplier anymore.`. and how `SupplierProduct`would be defined.